# How to get list of audio files in cordova 3.5

Tags: cordova

I need help from anyone who can tell me how to get the list of all audio files using cordova 3.5. This has bee frustrating me for a while now. Please someone should help me out

Answer (score 0):

A way could be using directory reader. You can read all the file names from a directory or directories and check which of them having the audio extensions.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#DirectoryReader

Comment: it's a pitty not all audio files are in the same folder .. at least for android